# Asp.net Identity Auto sign out after changing password

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

After `ChangePasswordAsync`, the user is signed out automatically and needs to sign in again. How can I keep the user signed in?

```
private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager
    {
        get
        {
            var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(Db);
            return new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
        }
    }


public bool ChangePassword(string oldPassword,string password)
    {
        var userId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var user = _userManager.ChangePasswordAsync(userId, oldPassword, password);
        if(!user.Result.Succeeded) return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: What problem? More information please.

Comment: Doing logged out after changing the user password.

Comment: Since you have a user manager, why don't you change the user object and let entity framework do its job? ` user.PasswordHash = UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(password); IdentityResult result = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `_userManager.ChangePasswordAsync`, modify directly `PasswordHash`:

```
var userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
var user = _userManager.Find(userName, oldPassword);
user.PasswordHash = UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(password); 
IdentityResult result = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
```